# Convert IPV4 to IPV6 php

Tags: php, ip, ipv6, ipv4

is there any way to covert IPV4 to IPV6 format Or vice-versa ? 
 When user registered or login to my site I am storing IP address in database.
 sometimes user's IPV6 formatted address storing.
 User's authentication is checking on ip address column. But next time user's   IPV4 formatted ip address is getting. So that in database I am not getting this IPV4 ip because stored IPV6 address previously.  and authentication of user is going to fail. So I want to convert IPV4 to IPV6.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the How to Ask page. You neew to provide some Information about what you have tried so far.

Comment: "converting" these types is not possible since they are not related to each other. IPv6 is a completely new form of IPs and is not created from an IPv4 address.

Answer (score 4):

IPv6 is not merely a different "format". IPv6 is a complete replacement of IPv4. There's no "conversion" of an IPv4 address to an IPv6 address. Your client either has an IPv4 address or they have an IPv6 address, period. Maybe they even have both, but that would only be because they run both IP stacks in parallel and can be reached via both methods; both stacks are running entirely independently of one another though, both may suddenly change their IPs independently. They're not correlated. As far as you know, each IP (whether v4 or v6) is an entirely different client.

In short: no. IPv6 is an entirely new address range. Imagine if IPv4 was extended from `255` as the maximum value for a byte to `512` and the whole new range `256.0.0.0` through `512.512.512.512` would become available; that's what IPv6 is.

Comment: An IPv4 can validly be expressed as an IPv6 address. It works the same way as expressing decimal numbers in HEX. `0.0.0.1` would be `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:0000:0001` and `123.123.123.123` would be `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:7b7b:7b7b` for example. It would, indeed, be impossible to convert most of the IPv6 addresses to IPv4, but the reverse is 100% possible.

Comment: That is fundamentally true, but *does it route to the same machine‽* Without that guarantee this sort of exercise is pointless.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses

Comment: Yeah, fine, but if you get any random IP address, do you know that it can be mapped that way to an address in the other stack which routes to the same machine? You mostly don’t. You can only do that if you know you’re in a stack that makes such a guarantee, which isn’t the case generally for the interweb.

Comment: What you are talking about is only a problem with specific operating systems (and distros). Most other systems do have dual-stack-sockets. E.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/dual-stack-sockets
`Any IPv4 addresses must be represented in the IPv4-mapped IPv6 address format which enables an IPv6 only application to communicate with an IPv4 node.`

Comment: No, you’re fundamentally missing something. Example: what about NAT? It’s extremely prevalent in IPv4. That means most IPv4s aren’t even globally routable and/or are shared between multiple machines. In IPv6, every machine has a unique globally routable address. **It simply does not translate.**

Comment: You're absolutely right about that. IPv4 can't be utilised to identify unique machines but assuming OP has decided to do that anyway (or perhaps it is not a problem in their case) they can use the mapping feature to make their node IPv6 only and mapping will allow users to utilise the service using an IPv4-mapped IPv6 address. It is important to mention here that an IPv4-mapped IPv6 will be different than the user's IPv6 if they have both enabled.

Comment: Yes, so, if you’re in a specific situation in which you can guarantee a mapping, then yes, you can. That’s not generally the case though.

Comment: An AF_INET6 socket can be used for IPv6 communications, IPv4 communications, or a mix of IPv6 and IPv4 communications.

If you want IPv6 specifically for a Socket, you can use IPV6_V6ONLY. Otherwise just use AF_INET6 as normal and be happy with IPv4 and IPv6. You can then map IPv4 to an IPv6 address ::ffff:127.0.0.1 for example. (just tested with a quick python server/client script)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are whitelisting the IP of each user during the initial registration process. If that is the case, then the issue you are experiencing is not easily resolvable. If your users have both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address, you will not be able to control which they use to connect to your server (aside from disabling IPv6 on your server). In addition, this method will not work for users with a dynamic IP address, as they will regularly get assigned a new IP and not be able to authenticate.

It is not possible to determine the users IPv4 address from their IPv6 address, as there is no guaranteed correlation between a user's IPv4 and IPv6 address*. As others have stated, IPv6 addresses do not directly convert into IPv4 addresses, as they are different formats. IPv6 addresses are much larger numbers (128-bit vs 32-bit), so converting an IPv6 address to IPv4 would not be possible even if the standard allowed for it.

*: the only exception I can think of on the correlation between IPv4 and IPv6 would be on a LAN with each device having a static private IP. If the static IPv4 and IPv6 addresses were selected so that they correlated somehow, then it would be possible to determine a v4 address from the v6 one. This is not a likely setup for most people though, and it assumes that your server is on the same local network as the end users (so that it would see the private IPs).

Given the high probability of locking out valid users (due to dynamic IPs or IPv6), this does not seem to be a reliable method of securing your server. If you have a very specific user base and dynamic IPs are not an issue, you might be able to bind your registration page to an IPv4 address and not have it listen on the IPv6 address. That way, you could at least be sure to get their IPv4 address at registration.

**Edit:** rewrote my answer to be more relavent to the question

Comment: More likely that he's using the IP address as part of the session identifier, which ends up invalidating the cookies when the user switches between IPv4 and IPv6.

Answer (score -1):

No info about storaging type(string, binary).

You can try this http://ipv6.ztsoftware.net/ipv4-to-ipv6/ but i'm not sure that is good idea. Seems like this service provide binary conversion. As said above, format of IPv4 and IPv6 - this is two different things.

Answer (score -2):

Accourding to [IPV4to6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6to4)

I created the following function for you in PHP, gues your looking for this:

```
function ipv4to6($ip=false) {

if (!$ip) {
    return;
}

$ipAddressBlocks = explode('.', $ip);

if (count($ipAddressBlocks) == 0) {
    return;
}

$ipv6       = '';
$ipv6Pieces = 0;
foreach ($ipAddressBlocks as $ipAddressBlock) {

    if ($ipv6Pieces%4 == 0 && $ipv6Pieces > 0) {
        $ipv6 .= '::';
    }

    $ipv6Piece = dechex($ipAddressBlock);
    $ipv6 .= (is_numeric($ipv6Piece) && $ipv6Piece < 10 ? '0'.$ipv6Piece : $ipv6Piece);

    $ipv6Pieces = strlen(str_replace('::', '', $ipv6));
}

return $ipv6.'::/48';
}
```

You can use this function like:

```
echo ipv4to6('192.0.2.4');
```

This will return: c000::0204::/48

Comment: The IPv6 address you get, `c000::0204::/48`, is `RESERVED` and not routed.